# How docker allocate memory to the process in container?

Tags: docker, runc

Docker first initializes a container and then execute the program you want. I wonder how docker manages the memory address of container and the program in it.

Comment: Which _memory address_?

Comment: Don't know about memory addresses but have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702233/docker-container-and-memory-consumption)?

Comment: It doesn't. The OS kernel manages the memory location of processes.running in the container.

Comment: So you mean the memory space of each process running in containers is allocated and managed by the OS. Then why can't we use `ps` command to see the process? Or how does the container in docker tell OS that there is a process needed to be allocated memory space?

Comment: @Henry is correct but you can define a memory per container by docker run -d -t --memory="512m"

Comment: This article: [What even is a container: namespaces and cgroups](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/10/10/what-even-is-a-container/) by Julia Evans has some interesting things that may help you.

Answer (score 3):

Docker does not allocate memory, it's the OS that manages the resources used by programs. Docker ([internally](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#the-underlying-technology)) uses [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) which is a kernel service. The reason that `ps` command (on the host) won't show up processes running in a container, is that containers run in different `cgroups` which are isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than worrying about the docker memory, you would need to look at the underlying host (VM/instance) where you are running the docker container. The number of containers is determined by a number of factors including what your app is that runs on the container. 
See here for the limits that you can run into [Is there a maximum number of containers running on a Docker host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799382/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-containers-running-on-a-docker-host)